# How to install printer Canon Pixma iP1800 on (x)ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, canon, pixma

Yesterday I reinstalled my friend's computer from Xubuntu 16.04 to 20.04. He used to print on his Canon Pixma iP1800 regularly. After this upgrade I am unable to find a way to install this priner.

Previously in Xubuntu 16.04 it works with this line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:michael-gruz/canon-trunk
```

In Xubuntu 20.04 it looks hopefully with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
```

But no luck because printer Canon Pixma iP1800 is missing in this repository for Ubuntu 20.04.(Focal Fossa)

How can I install Canon Pixma iP1800 on (x)ubuntu 20.04?

I appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 2):

I received answer from Mr. Thierry. He's guy who maintains repository for Canon printer drivers for Linux

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
```

> Hi,
>
> I am not Michael Gruz, I have taken over his work and modernized it.
> ia32 does not exist anymore.
>
> Ubuntu has decided to ban the i386 from PPAs since version 20.04
>
> I suggest you use the Disco (Disco Dingo = Ubuntu 19.04) versions, they are compatible.  From now
> on, you have to proceed differently, I give you the procedure below:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
>
> wget https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/+files/cnijfilter-ip1800series_4.10+3.5.4-1904ubuntu1_i386.deb
> wget https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz/+files/cnijfilter-common_4.10+3.5.4-1904ubuntu1_i386.deb
>
> sudo apt update
> sudo dpkg -i --force-all ./cnijfilter-ip1800series_4.10+3.5.4-1904ubuntu1_i386.deb ./cnijfilter-common_4.10+3.5.4-1904ubuntu1_i386.deb
> sudo apt install -f
> ```
>
> Thierry

This solution works for my 2 computers with Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and Xubuntu 20.04 like a charm